# Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

```
<ref id="ch02_ref1"><mixed-citation publication-type="journal"><person-group person-group-type="author"><name><surname>J.M.</surname><given-names>Astilleros</given-names></name>
```

This is a single line. I just need to extract the word between the tags `<given-names>` and `</given-names>` which in this case is **Astilleros**. Is there a regex to do this. The problem I am facing is that there is no space between each word and the end tag `</given-names>` where '/' is a character in perl regex.. please help..

The idea is to get the names out, find them in the text on the page and put `<given-names>Astilleros</given-names>` tags around them.. I will definitely try XML parsers..

Comment: To use / in a Perl regular expression, you can employ an alternate set of delimiters such as `{}`: `m{<given-names>.*?</given-names>}`.

Comment: This is a snippet of a larger XML statement. If you have the whole statement, you should use an XML parser to get your data.

Comment: The idea is to get the names out, find them in the text on the page and put <given-names>Astilleros</given-names> tags around them.. I will definitely try XML parsers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse XML with regexes – it is just too damn hard to get right. There are good parsers lying around, just waiting to be utilized by you. Let's use [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'END');
<ref id="ch02_ref1">
  <mixed-citation publication-type="journal">
    <person-group person-group-type="author">
      <name>
        <surname>J.M.</surname>
        <given-names>Astilleros</given-names>
      </name>
    </person-group>
  </mixed-citation>
</ref>
END

# use XPath to find your element
my ($name) = $dom->findnodes('//given-names');
print $name->textContent, "\n";
```

(whatever you try, do not use XML::Simple!)

Comment: This gives me the error `Can't locate object method "textContent" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"`. And the documentation is rather horrible.

Comment: @TLP Thanks, I corrected it. The docs are horribly, but most of it is just standard DOM, as seen in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as as a regex:

```
/<given-names>(.*?)</
```

From your input, it will capture `Astilleros`

This matches:

- A literal `<given-names>`
- Captures (0 to infinite times) any character (except newline)
- Until it reaches a literal `<`

Comment: Tried and worked wonders but doesn't work with 2 part names like Jean Luc like Thilo said. Thank you for the expression..

Comment: It should - did you use my most recent regex?

Comment: I just ran it on: `<ref id="ch02_ref1"><mixed-citation publication-type="journal"><person-group person-group-type="author"><name><surname>J.M.</surname><given-names>jean-luc Mcnichollson</given-names></name>` which captures: `jean-luc Mcnichollson`